# How to solve this "does not live long enough"?

Tags: rust

There is some minimal example library code I would like to use:

```
struct MyR<'a> {
    x: &'a str,
}

struct T {
    x: &'static str,
}

impl T {
    fn bar<'a>(&'a self) -> MyR {
        MyR { x: self.x }
    }
}
```

The following is my code:

```
trait A<R, F: FnMut(&R)> {
    fn foo(&mut self, callback: &mut F);
}

impl<'a, F> A<MyR<'a>, F> for T
    where F: FnMut(&MyR<'a>)
{
    fn foo(&mut self, callback: &mut F) {
        let t = T { x: "l" };
        let r = t.bar(); // t does not live long enough (for 'a)
        callback(&r);
        println!("abc");
    }
}

fn test() {
    let mut t = T { x: "l" };
    let mut i = 1;
    t.foo(&mut |x| { i += x.x.len(); });
}
```

I would like to make a trait that is parametrized by the callback, but I struggled to make it right. If I don't use a trait, it works well:

```
impl T {
    fn foo<F: FnMut(&MyR)>(&mut self, callback: &'a mut F) {
        let t = T { x: "l" };
        let r = t.bar();
        callback(&r);
        println!("abc");
    }
}
```

But I cannot do this:

```
impl T {
    fn foo<'a, F: FnMut(&MyR<'a>)>(&mut self, callback: &mut F) {
        let t = T { x: "l" };
        let r = t.bar();
        callback(&r);
        println!("abc");
    }
}
```

I know the problem is that `t` must outlive `'a`, but I don't know to bound `'a` so that its lifetime is shorter than `t`.

I'm using rustc 1.19.0-nightly.

Answer (score 2):

Read the error messages:

1. *`t` does not live long enough* — it lives until the end of the `foo` function.
2. *borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a* — **you** have specified `'a`:

   ```
   impl<'a, F> A<MyR<'a>, F> for T
       where F: FnMut(&MyR<'a>)
   ```

   This says that for *any possible lifetime*, the trait will be implemented, so long as `F` implements the `FnMut` trait.

There's only **one** possible way to make that work — you have to have a `MyR` that is parameterized with the `'static` lifetime. That's the only lifetime that is guaranteed to outlive any arbitrary lifetime.

Let's see where `MyR` comes from:

```
fn bar<'a>(&'a self) -> MyR {
    MyR { x: self.x }
}
```

If you go back and reread [*The Rust Programming Language* section on lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/lifetimes.html#lifetime-elision), you'll recognize that this lifetime specification provides no value. It defines a lifetime and uses it with `self`, but it's never tied to any output lifetimes. The code is the same as:

```
fn bar<'a, 'b>(&'a self) -> MyR<'b>
```

If you removed the lifetime, then you'd have

```
fn bar(&self) -> MyR
fn bar<'a>(&'a self) -> MyR<'a> // equivalent
```

However, neither of these is the `'static` lifetime. Luckily for you, you know that that `x` is a `&'static str`, so you can just reflect that in your signature and the code will compile:

```
fn bar(&self) -> MyR<'static>
```

Comment: I am not able to change the lib code. I can only change my code. Is there no way I can make a trait that abstract `fn foo<F: FnMut(&MyR)>(&mut self, callback: &'a mut F) `?

Answer (score 0):

Spending hours trying different approaches, this seems to work

```
trait A<F> {
    fn foo(&mut self, callback: &mut F);
}

impl<F> A<F> for T
    where F: FnMut(&MyR)
{
    fn foo(&mut self, callback: &mut F) {
        let t = T { x: "l" };
        let r = t.bar(); // t does not live long enough (for 'a)
        callback(&r);
        println!("abc");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut t = T { x: "l" };
    let mut i = 1;
    t.foo(&mut |x: &MyR| { i += x.x.len(); });

}
```

The main difference is:

- I have to loose trait a bit so that it takes arbitrary types.
- So that when I impl I don't have to specify lifetime at all.
- I have to type annotate the closure when invoking the function.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a06fe5bbf18eabd374f2c3f9aab3df00&version=stable&backtrace=0)